# How do you set up a chat room without being told to do so?

Tags: discussion, chat

On occasion I have been at fault for getting into discussions with members when asking a question. The trouble is I don't know how to set up a chat room without seeing the link that is visible after to much chatter. Is there a way to do this? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head over to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), scroll down to the bottom and click "create a new room". Or, if you like, you can come to the [general room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ask [a moderator](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) to move the comments on the post to chat manually (no link required). There's usually *someone* around ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like the automatic chatroom, where comments are imported, you can't:  it's [a pending feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96247/270345).